# JAVA: get variable of object using tree map method

Tags: java, treemap

Say I have an object called **Car**:

```
public class Car(){
  String model;
  String brand;
  Integer yearReleased;
  float price;
}
```

and create a treemap of cars called **cars**:

```
TreeMap<Integer, Car> cars = new TreeMap<Integer, Car>();
```

Is there a method wherein I can search up the model of a car in the treelist? Something like **.getKey()** but allows to search an object variable. I'm trying to create a search function wherein it has a parameter of the treemap and the model to be searched and returns the key.

```
public searchModel(TreeMap<Integer, Car> list, String model){
  return list.getKey(model);
}
```

Comment: No, you have to have separate map for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no relationship between the model and the Integer key of the map, you have no choice but to iterate over all its values:

```java
public List<Car> searchModel(TreeMap<Integer, Car> map, String model){
  return map.values()
            .stream()
            .filter(c -> c.model.equals(model))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, I was just wondering how to get the input to be a string or something readable. When I print the list using -Arrays.toString- it it gives me [project.Car@65b3120a] instead

Comment: @rr11 You need to override Car's toString() mehos

Comment: OP asked to return the key rather than the value. That'd be `entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue().model.equals(model)).map(e -> e.getKey()).toList()`